# How to refresh a page after the form response comes back

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql, ajax

I have searched about my problem in several websites, but I could not get it. What I am looking for is how to refresh a page after response comes back with successful message of deletion of row. My page admin2.php displays the information of admin from DB as well as the table (from DB) of students which has also a checkbox beside each row of the student. I am sending the form (table) over Ajax to go to (admin3Response.php) page to check and then get back with a response. here is my code which has a problem.

admin2.php

```
      <tr><th>Admin Information</th>
        <th style="width: 212px"></th></tr>
      <tr><td><b>Admin Name: <?php echo $name; ?></b><span name="adminName"></span></td>
        <td style="width: 212px"><b>Admin ID: <?php echo $userID; ?></b><span name="adminID"></span></td></tr>
      <tr><td><b>Phone: <?php echo $phone; ?></b><span name="adminPhone"></span></td>
        <td style="width: 212px"><span></span></td></tr>
```

admin2.php
This is a form what I want to be refreshed. from this table I can select which student I want to delete.

```
else if(isset($dropStudent))
{

if(mysql_num_rows($QueryResult7) == 0)
  {
            ?>
    <h2><?php echo ("There are no students available.");?></h2>
    <p>
    <div class="form_settings">
    <input class="submit" type="button" onclick="goBack()" name="delete0" value="Back" style="margin-left: 0px; width: 89px">
    </div>
    <?php
     }
else 
{
?>

<form name="form3" id ="form3" method="" action="admin2.php"  >
<input type="hidden" value="Delete" name="deleteStudent">
<?php
echo $adminUser;
?>
<TABLE style="width:100%; border-spacing:1;">


<TR><TH>Choose</TH><TH>USER_ID</TH><TH>STUDENT NAME</TH><TH>EMAIL</TH><TH>PHONE</TH>                   <TH>MAJOR</TH><TH>GPA</TH><TH>DEGREE</TH></TR>
<?php

$Row7 = mysql_fetch_row($QueryResult7);
// reads row of query into indexed array
// advances result pointer
do
{
echo '<TR><TD><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="' . $Row7[0] .  '"></TD>'            .
"<TD>{$Row7[0]}</TD>

<TD>{$Row7[1]}</TD>" .
"<TD>{$Row7[2]}</TD>

<TD>{$Row7[3]}</TD>" .
"<TD>{$Row7[4]}</TD>

<TD>{$Row7[5]}</TD>" .
"<TD>{$Row7[6]}</TD>

</TR>";

$Row7 = mysql_fetch_row($QueryResult7);

} while ($Row7); // tests for content of null

?>

<input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $countStds; ?>" name="countStds">
<input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $adminUser; ?>" name="adminUser">


<tr>
<td colspan="10">
```

```
</tr>
<?php
mysql_close($DBConnect);
?>
</TABLE>
</form>
<script>
// $("#form3") grabs the above form with an ID of "form3"
$("#form3").on('submit', function(){

    // Grab all form values
    var values = $("#form3").serialize();
    // Send form values over ajax
    $.ajax({
        method: 'POST',
        url: 'admin3Response.php',
        data: values,
        // execute when response comes back from admin3Response.php
        success: function(data){
            // data = whatever admin3Response echo'd back
            // check for success
            if (data.lastIndexOf("success") >= 0) {

                // no errors
                    alert("Student was dropped successfully");

        window.location.reload(true); // It reload an empty page; didn't work
                //alert("TODO: redirect user somewhere?");
            } else {
                // Display error message
                alert(data);
            }
        }
    })
    return false;
});
  </script>          
  <?php

  }
  }
```

admin3Response.php

```
else if(isset($deleteStudent))

{

 if (isset($checkbox))
{       

 for($i=0; $i<$countStds; $i++)
{
    $delStudent = $checkbox[$i];
    $wholeStudents = mysql_query("DELETE USERS, ENROLLMENTS, OVERIDES FROM          USERS, ENROLLMENTS, OVERIDES WHERE USERS.USER_ID = ENROLLMENTS.USER_ID AND   ENROLLMENTS.USER_ID = OVERIDES.USER_ID AND USERS.USER_ID = '$delStudent'"); 
    $delUserStudent = mysql_query("DELETE USERS FROM USERS WHERE USER_ID =    '$delStudent'");
    $delOverStudent = mysql_query("DELETE OVERIDES, USERS FROM OVERIDES, USERS  WHERE USERS.USER_ID = OVERIDES.USER_ID AND USERS.USER_ID = '$delStudent'");
    $delEnrStudent = mysql_query("DELETE ENROLLMENTS, USERS FROM ENROLLMENTS,  USERS WHERE USERS.USER_ID = ENROLLMENTS.USER_ID AND USERS.USER_ID = '$delStudent'");     
}

 echo ("You have deleted "); echo count($checkbox);  echo (" student(s)   `enter code here`successfully."); 


echo ("success");
 }
 else
 { 
 echo ("No student selected"); 
 }

 mysql_close($DBConnect);    

 }
```

I tried using "window.location.reload(true);", but it reload an empty page. My guess is I need to use get method to pass all the variables from admin3Response.php to admin2.php but I don't know how to do it. Any help would appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

A lot of ways, I suppose you can do Like:

```
    window.location.reload();
    history.go(0);
    window.location.href=window.location.href;
```

if you want to redirect to another page change

```
 window.location="Path"
```

Comment: it must work at least with window.location="admin2.php", else is there some error messages?

Comment: It gave me an empty table without any information populated from DB just the labels (html).

Comment: then i think the problem come from php

Comment: I defined it above of the admin2.php ($dropStudent = $_POST['dropStudent'];) which is coming from admin.php page

Comment: everything works fine and delete a student but the page doesn't get refreshed so that I have to refresh manually.

Comment: When u submit, do u receive the alert(Student was dropped successfully);?

Comment: Yes, I receive this message and the deletion did happen, but I have to refresh the page manually to see the current students after deletion.

Comment: Ok let us try this one, may be it can help:                on('submit', function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  return false;
});

Answer (score 0):

Tried this?

```
if (data.lastIndexOf("success") >= 0) {
    // no errors
    alert("Student was dropped successfully");
    window.location = window.location;
}
```

Comment: I already used that, but it is not working. It just reloaded an empty page.